# Spy or secret identity game

Tags: identify-this-game

I don't have as much information about the game as I wish.  I played it back in the 80's so it is at least that old.  It was a board game typical size and had squares around the edge of the board that you moved around with real life pictures of people.  I believe each person was assigned one of the people and they had a role and you tried to either figure out who the spy was or who everyone was.  I loved playing at my Aunt's as a kid but last time I went there and thought about it I couldn't find it.  Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The MSN homepage had a link to an article of the top game that game out the year you were born so I looked through it and in 1976 Parker Brothers released **WHOSIT?**, which is the game I wanted to identify and discovered by luck.

Answer (score 3):

This sounds like Top Secret Spies, also known as Heimlich and co.

link to [bgg](https://boardgamegeek.com/boardgame/382/heimlich-co)

This game came out in 1984.  Players are all allocated a secret character and they move around the edge of the board so it fits your description.  Players could move any piece but when a piece landed on the safe all characters scored points depending on position on the board.

Comment: For a game with the name "Heimlich", I love to see the choking hazard message for the small parts...